# Torus as CW complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

How can I show that a torus is a CW complex?

I have seen an answer where they are taking one 0-cell, two 1-cell and one 2-cell to construct the torus. But, I don't understand how they are attaching $X^{(1)}$ to $D^2$ to form a torus?

Can anyone give a precise pushout and also a visual argument?

Comment: It's easier to think of $D^2$ as a square. Gluing each part of opposite sides (with the same orientation so that the word encoding this is $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$) we get a torus. And once we do this gluing, the boundary square becomes $X^{(1)}$, the wedge of two circles.

Comment: @Tabes Bridges I am not getting one part, what's the map from $S^1$ to $S^1 V S^1$ ? Will you please tell me this?

Comment: You divide $S^1$ into four arcs, and map each arc to a circle. The word $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ indicates that the first arc covers one circle, the second arc covers the other, then the third arc covers the first circle but in the other direction, and the fourth arc covers the second circle in the other direction.

Comment: Great!!! Thanks a lot! I got it! By the way, what's the reason for the notation $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ ,is there anything related to group?

Comment: Yes, the fundamental group of $S^1 \vee S^1$ is the free group on two letters, so since the attaching map for a $2$-cell is actually a loop in $S^1 \vee S^1$, we can describe it up to homotopy by a unique reduced word in $a$ and $b$. You can also connect this to the theory of (normal) covering spaces of $S^1 \vee S^1$, since they correspond to subgroups of that free group (and the actions of those subgroups on the tree that universally covers $S^1 \vee S^1$).

Comment: Can you give me some references in this regard? Another question, which spaces can be realised as cw complexes? Can we give a precise description?

Comment: Certainly Chapter 1 of Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* is where I know 95+% of this from. And although I have never read it I would assume that Serre's *Trees*, which is about the Bass-Serre theory of group actions on trees and their relation to the structure of free groups, is also relevant. I don't know much of anything about the "which spaces are CW complexes" question other than 1) any compact manifold should have the structure of a CW complex (I don't know a reference)...

Comment: ...and 2) any complex submanifold of $\mathbb C^N$ which has (complex) dimension $n$ has the *homotopy type* of a CW complex of real dimension $n$ (this is a theorem of Andreotti and Frankel). I mention both results because generally people who are interested in categories of CW complexes are interested in things "up to homotopy" rather than "on the nose."